# Creating a Python Pipeline on Jenkins but get access denied from docker

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I've created a `Jenkinsfile` in my Git repository that is defined as this:

```
pipeline {
//None parameter in the agent section means that no global agent will be allocated for the entire Pipeline’s
//execution and that each stage directive must specify its own agent section.
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    //This image parameter (of the agent section’s docker parameter) downloads the python:3.8
                    //Docker image and runs this image as a separate container. The Python container becomes
                    //the agent that Jenkins uses to run the Build stage of the Pipeline project.
                    image 'python:3.8.3'
                }
            }
            steps {
                //This sh step runs the Python command to compile the application
                sh 'pip install -r requirements.txt'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I tried to run the job with this Pipeline, I've got the following error:
[image: Job Error]

I also tried to use `image python:latest` but this option didn't work either.

Can someone explain me :)?

Comment: Looks like the image was pulled successfully and you're running into a file permissions issue.

Comment: OK, do you know where I can access the permission in order to let Jenkins run properly? @StephenNewell

Answer (score 0):

Go to Computer Management -> Local Users and Groups and make sure the user used by jenkins is added to the `docker-users` group

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Do you mean the management in my localhost Docker Desktop? because I don't see such an option